# Installing IIS on windows 10

Tags: iis

I'm trying to connect Java to mysql on a windows 10 machine.  I was told that I first needed to install IIS.  I've done this but when I go to localhost in my browser I get:

```
HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error

Handler "StaticFile" has a bad module "DefaultDocumentModule" in its module list
```

I'm not sure what to do at this point

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled IIS and reinstalled and now it works